# How can I create view model per fragment inside viewpage

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

Basically I want to create view model per fragment in view pager. each page in the view pager has different data to fetch from network.

View pager -> view pager adapter -> fragment with view model

Since all of these fragment using same view model, data in each page is replicating with same content.

productsViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)
.get(categoryName!!, ProductsViewModel::class.java)

having category name doesn't work, because it still uses the same view model.

Can you give us idea what could be the best for situation ??

Comment: You don't need to do anything. Normally different ViewModel instance is created when you pass different `fragment` instance in `ViewModelProviders.of(fragment)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using simple logic. prepare your **ViewPager** dynamically with data they required for setup. Here, I had prepared **view pager** with same **fragment** multiple time as you can set your **ViewPager** with different fragment. :)

```
 private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager, Data yourData) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        for (int i = 0; i < tabTitleList.size(); i++) {
            adapter.addFragment(new YourFragment(), tabTitleList.get(i),yourData.getData().get(i));
        }

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

---

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title, Data yourData) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("key",yourData);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not good idea for several reasons, you are having all the page data upfront before you setting up adapter. in that case it will simple not provide you better user experience. view will not ready until all those network call fetches data. it will make user to wait for longer. this is not okey when you have 6 to 7 pages in viewpager . more over you will be holding heavy weight object . every page in the view page should have their own view model populate the data. but here thing is view model been used across all the pages and reflecting same data which is some thing I have to overcome

Answer (score 0):

[Sanlok Lee is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57244902/how-can-i-create-view-model-per-fragment-inside-viewpage/57279381#comment100991415_57244902):

> You don't need to do anything. Normally different ViewModel instance is created when you pass different `fragment` instance in `ViewModelProviders.of(fragment)`

what i am doing wrong then, I am keeping all the page data(network data) in a table, and I am not querying them based page category. hence all the data was replicating same in all the page.